# json pattern display in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, json

I am  having json pattern like this

```
output = (
    {
        id = {
            php = 1;
        };
        image =             {
            1 = "http://www.easyteach.gr/users/tutor/1432636961.jpg";
        };
        name =             {
            php = ramkumar;
        };
    },
    {
        id = {
            android = 1;
        };
        image = {
            3 = "http://www.easyteach.gr/users/tutor/1432636961.jpg";
        };
        name = {
            android = Vijayan;
        };
    },
```

I want to display `output->name->php` and `output->name->android` both in the same array.

This is my code:

```
nameArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"output.name"];
        NSLog(@"%@",nameArray);
```

Comment: question is not clear.

Comment: exactly what value you want to fetch?

Comment: ramkumar and vijayan @AbhinandanPratap

Comment: So you get an array of dictionaries but you want an array of strings? How have you thought about dealing with that?

Comment: i convert dict into array as name after i want to print the individual name here php and android is there how to fetch ? and its possible to fetch in same array? @Wain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
NSArray *output; //your output array got from server

NSDictionary *dict = [output objectAtIndex:0];

NSDictionary *dict2 = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];

NSString *str = [dict2 objectForKey:@"php"];
```

same for android, you can use `objectAtIndex : 1` instead `0`

And make sure your response at `android = Vijayan;` or `php = ramkumar;` if it is wrong.

hope this will help :)

Comment: ya its working again i had a drought for e.g. i had objectAtIndex 5 and object for key ("3" values of "php" ) and object for key ("2" values of "android") means i want to code for each index? @Lion

Comment: you can go loop through if it is in proper format. use for loop

Comment: you're welcome.... :)

Answer (score 1):

## A.sonu You get wrong json formate.

```
output->name->php and output->name->Android
```

android and php is a key there php value is php = ramkumar;
How we get this key ("php","android")

```
name =   ramkumar;
name =  Vijayan;
```

So we can find get this value with name key.

Comment: your point of view its wrong but object for key "name"contain "php" and "android".please kindly check above json pattern @Pitambar Indoria

Comment: but #A.sonu object for key "name" contain php and android value but how you get android and php key value when you want to get ramkumar and vijayan